# Working with Alias and try_files witn nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have been trying to get this to work for most of the afternoon and have tried several of the solution I have seen online with no luck. I have tried putting the $uri twice, but cant get the try_files to pick up my other images size. Any help would be greatly appreciated (exmaples).

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com;

        root /web/mysite.com;

        location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        }

# directory based redirects
                location /mimg/ {
                                                alias /web/mysite.com/images/;
                # cache expiration
                                expires 30d;
                # set default error page
                set $error_page_404 /samples/_default.jpg;
                # failover chain samples (16:9 content flag set)
                                location ~* ^/samples-304x171/(.*)$ {
                                                set $error_page_404 /samples/_default-16x9.jpg;
                                }
                                location ~* ^/samples-400x225/(.*)$ {
                                                try_files $uri /samples-304x171/$1;
                                }
                                location ~* ^/samples-640x360/(.*)$ {
                                                try_files $uri /samples-400x225/$1;
                                }
                                location ~* ^/samples-800x450/(.*)$ {
                                                try_files $uri /samples-640x360/$1;
                                }
                # set default image
                error_page 404 $error_page_404;
            } # end of /mimg
}
```

Comment: The outer `location` matches URIs that begin with `/mimg/`, but the inner `location` blocks only match URIs that begin with `/samples-` - so they will never match anything.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is it possible to post an actual example. As I'm not to savvy with nginx?

Comment: What is the full URL of the images you are trying to access? I presume they live on the files system at `/web/mysite.com/images/samples-640x360/foo.jpg`

Comment: I got it right after I posted. Thanks again